# Address translation in systems with paging

Tags: operating-system, hardware, paging, memory-address

How does address translation work in systems with paging (without virtual memory)? What is done by the hardware and by the operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software maintains the pages tables that defines the mapping of logical pages to physical page frames. The hardware does the translation of addresses from logical to physical using the page tables.

The format of the page tables depends entirely upon the processor and there are several structures in use.